# Ant table unique key warning

Tags: reactjs, antd, unique-key

I get the following warning when using ant table component

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `Body`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at BodyRow (http://localhost:3000/proj/static/js/bundle.js:202144:25)
    at Body (http://localhost:3000/proj/static/js/bundle.js:202467:19)
    at table
    at div
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/proj/static/js/bundle.js:203460:23
    at div
    at Table (http://localhost:3000/proj/static/js/bundle.js:203475:25)
```

This is how I use it. I am aware I must have unique keys for each of the columns.

```
<Table
    pagination={false}
    rowKey={'key'} // I tried this also
    dataSource={data}
   >
                <Column
                    title={t("geometryView.geometryInfo.geometryInfoTable.name")}
                    width={'10%'}
                    dataIndex="name"
                    key="name" />
                <Column
                    title={t("geometryView.geometryInfo.geometryInfoTable.vertices")}
                    dataIndex="vertices"
                    key="vertices" />
</Table>
```

And this is the data:

```
data.push({
      key: d.key, // this is unique
      name: d.name,
      vertices: d.vertices,
})
```

I also tried adding the rowKey property to the table, that didn't work.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: are you using the `map` method on `data` and showing the table or how ?

Comment: No, it's a plain element, like this
 <Panel panelHeight={panelHeight}>
            <h4>{t("translation.key")}</h4>
            <Table.....
            </Table>
</Panel>

Even if the data in empty, I still get the error.

Comment: I guess `data` doesn't have uniques keys

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
<Table
    pagination={false}
    rowKey={record => record.id} // or rowKey='id' 
    dataSource={data}
   >
```